# Linked images not included when a file is 'Packaged' in Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am using Illustrator to create a layout with multiple images on it. I tried to create a Package of the artwork and its contents (File→Package), it works fine except that the folder that should contain the Linked images is missing. I checked the options to Copy links in a separate folder.

[image: Options Dialog Box]

Comment: Are these linked or embedded?

Comment: @Lucian I manually linked them while creating the layout. However when I open the Links Panel it says 'Embedded File' against 'Format'.

Comment: Worth reading re linked vs embedded: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/importing-artwork-files.html

Answer (score 2):

If these are embedded, the link is gone and they will be skipped when packaging. Replace the images via 'File → Place' and make sure you **don't** embed them again.

Embedding images will also considerably increase the file size of your AI source.

Comment: You can relink an embedded file by clicking the filename in the options bar (or from the links panel), no need to actually "File > place" it again

Comment: @Lucian Thanks. However, there seems to be a larger issue as I created a new File and 'placed' a few new images and created a Package. Same result—no 'Linked Images' folder. It seems like the images that are getting placed are embedded by default. The 'Unembed' button gets active as soon as the image is placed besides the fact that the information window that opens when I click on the Linked item in the Links Panel says 'Embedded File' for all images I use.